# php won't post value to email

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have added a button onclick function to a web form, so that onClick new input text field is created. However when the forms posts to email, Quote_Num value isn't posted - it just says "Array"

JS

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 8;
function addInput(divName) {
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Quote Number " + (counter + 1) + " <p><input type='text' name='Quote_Num[]' /></p>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="dynamicInput">
    Quote Number
    <p><input type="text" id="Quote_Num" name="Quote_Num[]" class="required" /> *</p>
</div>  
<p><button type="button" value="Add another text input" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">Add Quote Number</button></p>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$Quote_Num = $_POST["Quote_Num"];
foreach ($Quote_Num as $eachInput) 
{
     echo $eachInput . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Anyone with my experience with PHP help me get the form to post value of Quote_Num?

Comment: Please specify what do you mean by post to email. Does the PHP code you posted gives correct output? Like, does it list all the values?

Comment: Apologies, the form submits to an email - however the value entered in the Quote_Num text input doesn't submit, instead it shows as "Quote_Num: Array" rather than "Quote Num: Entered Value"

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_dump($Quote_Num);`, so we can see the array structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$Quote_Num` set with `$Quote_Num = $_POST["Quote_Num"];` is an array, as you are submitting more then one values values from your HTML form by setting name equal to `Quote_Num[]`.

If you `echo` an `Array` in PHP, It will give an Notice, and print 'Array'.

If you want all of the values of the array `$Quote_Num` you can use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on Array. For example `implode(", ", $Quote_Num)` will return comma separated list of all values in the array as String.

You may also print the whole array by using `var_dump` or `print_r`.

I hope, I got your question and it helps.